# How to make CMake compile a specific target without parallel jobs

Tags: cmake, build, ninja

I have a big CMakeLists with a lot of targets. One of them (specifically one C++ file in one library) is taking a lot of memory to compile and is making my CI pipeline run out of memory.

I would like the compilation to reduce to one simultaneous job when compiling this file, then resume parallel compilation when finished.
I looked at Ninja job pools, but it will only allow me to compile a specific target (e.g. the library) in one job, without constraining the other targets.

Is there a way to do so, if possible without manually adding dependencies to this library?

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the target that you want to build without object-level parallelism "`heavy_target`". If the problem is specifically with `heavy_target` and not with the combination of itself and its dependencies, then you can do the following: build all the dependencies of `heavy_target` first with whatever parallelism you want, then build `heavy_target` with no parallelism, then build everything else (or build everything and let the buildsystem detect that `heavy_target` and all its dependencies have been built).

```bash
cmake --build <binary_dir> --target <dep1> <dep2> <dep3> <...> <other args>
cmake --build <binary_dir> --target heavy_target --parallel 1 <other args>
cmake --build <binary_dir> <other args>
```

When building `heavy_target`'s dependencies, you should only need to list the direct dependencies, and the generated buildsystem will know about the transitive ones.

`<other args>` might be things like `--config <config>`, `--parallel <jobs>`, etc. see [the docs on arguments to the cmake command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-j).

If it's inconvenient to read through the cmake files to find out all the dependencies of `heavy_target`, you can get a list of the link-libraries of `heavy_target` by reading the [`LINK_LIBRARIES` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html):

```
get_property(heavy_target_link_libraries TARGET heavy_target PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES)
message("direct deps of heavy_target: ${heavy_target_link_libraries}")
```

Inlining the asker's comment: "*It should also be possible to create a custom phony target depending on all `heavy_target`'s dependencies.*"